# Xamarin Studio for mac standalone Xamarin.ios installer

Tags: ios, macos, xamarin.ios, mono, visual-studio-2017

### Symptoms

Recently installed Visual Studio 2017 which included Xamarin.iOS 10.4. I also have a Macintosh with x-code and Xamarin Studio community installed. The problem is that the Xamarin Studio on my mac has version 10.3. Attempting to upgrade to 10.4 by switching xamarin to the beta channel by checking for updates causes the `Mono Framework MDK 4.8.0.478` to fail along with `Xamarin.iOS 10.4.0.97`. Attempting to access the [downloads page](https://store.xamarin.com/account/my/subscription/downloads) (you will need to login to see the page) only allows downloads up to `Xamarin.iOS 10.3.1`.

Is there a way to do any of the following:

1. Repair the downloader (Xamarin Update).
2. Manually download Xamarin.iOS 10.4.
3. Fallback from 10.4 -> 10.3 in Visual Studio on the Windows PC side.

---

Xamarin Studio logs can be provided upon request, but I couldn't find anything about errors or failures in them because they only wrote out events regarding installation success rather than downloading status.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do #2 if you know the exact version numbers. Here are the download links for:

**Xamarin.iOS 10.4**
https://dl.xamarin.com/MonoTouch/Mac/xamarin.ios-10.4.0.97.pkg 

Plug in other numbers like: https://dl.xamarin.com/MonoTouch/Mac/xamarin.ios-10.3.1.8.pkg to get 10.3.

**Xamarin Studio 4.0**
http://download.xamarin.com/studio/Mac/XamarinStudio-4.0.12-3.dmg

**Xamarin Studio 6.1** 
https://dl.xamarin.com/MonoDevelop/Mac/XamarinStudio-6.1.5.0.dmg

**Xamarin for Visual Studio 4.2**
http://dl.xamarin.com/XamarinforVisualStudio/Windows/Xamarin.VisualStudio_4.2.0.719.msi

download.xamarin.com must have been the old paths because XS 6.1.5.0 is not available on it.

Comment: Even though I went to the mono website and installed the correct Mono MDK, the updater still tries to fail-download mono. However, the link you provided allowed me to put my Xamarin studio in a working state for my PC to build to it.